# Scripting in gdb

Tags: gdb

Say, for example, I have a C source file with a method like `foo(a)` where `a` is a character.

I want to print the output of `foo` for every character is there an easier way than going through systematically and entering `p foo('a')` then `p foo('b')`?

Ideally I'd really like to script it so it's a bit quicker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, my code was basically:

```
define foo_test
    set $a = 97
    set $b = 123

    while $a < $b
        p (char)foo($a)
        set $a = $a + 1
    end
end
```

Comment: And then run the script by just typing 'foo_test' at the gdb prompt.

If you create this in a text editor and then paste it in be sure to use spaces not tabs.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'foreach $i ("a" .. "z") { print "print foo('\''$i'\'')\n"; }' > /tmp/t.$$ &&
gdb --batch -x /tmp/t.$$ ./a.out ; rm -f /tmp/t.$$
```

You should also look into GDB Python [scripting](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first thing you should add is some "Breakpoint command lists", 
those will let you run some gdb commands after a breakpoint has hit.

So if you add so your print runs when someone calls the functions foo, 
you should be are getting kind of close.